# Asignar un valor acorde con el valor de varias columnas

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe como este:

```
         BQPREVIO          ASMAPREVIO    bronquitis_cronica         expectoración   silibancias ENFISEMA PREVIO

             1                 2                1                          1            1               1
             2                2                1                          1            1               1
             2                2               1                          1            2               1
             1                 2                1                          2            1               1
             1                 2                1                          1            2               1
             1                 2                1                        1            2               1
             2                1                1                          1            2               1
             2                 2                1                          1            2               1
             1                 1                1                          1            2               1
             1                 2                1                          2            1              1
```

Estos valores valen 2 = Si y 1 = No

Quiero categorizar por niveles:

```
 Tipo I   Todos No
 Tipo II   Efisema Si
 Tipo III  Broquitis crónica o expectoración  o BQPREVIO
 Tipo IV   Silibancias o ASMAPREVIO
```

He intentado resolver este rpboema uniendo cada fila con la función unite:

BD_table6_1<-unite(BD_table6_1,total,c(1,2,3,4,5,6),sep="_",remove= FALSE)

```
       BD_table6_1$GESEPOCFENOTIPO_TipoI<-ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "1_1_1_1_1_1" , "1",
                                      ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "1_1_1_1_1_2" , "2",
                                             ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "1_1_2_1_1_1" , "3",
                                                    ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "1_1_1_2_1_1" , "3",
                                                           ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "2_1_1_1_1_1" , "3",
                                                                  ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "1_1_2_2_1_1" , "3",
                                                                         ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "2_1_2_1_1_1" , "3",
                                                                                ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "2_1_2_1_1_1" , "3",
                                                                                   ifelse(BD_table6_1$total == "1_2_1_1_2_1" , "4", "0")))))))))
```

Aunque funciona, me queda una linea de código horrible. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo que no sea tan engorrosa?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un buen caso para usar `case_when()`, por que permite escribir cada condición y evaluarla de forma secuencial:

```
BD_table6_1 %>% 
  unite(total,c(1,2,3,4,5,6),sep="_",remove= FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(GESEPOCFENOTIPO_TipoI = case_when(
                                  total == "1_1_1_1_1_1" ~ "1",
                                  total == "1_1_1_1_1_2" ~ "2",
                                  total == "1_1_2_1_1_1" ~ "3",
                                  total == "1_1_1_2_1_1" ~ "3",
                                  total == "2_1_1_1_1_1" ~ "3",
                                  total == "1_1_2_2_1_1" ~ "3",
                                  total == "2_1_2_1_1_1" ~ "3",
                                  total == "2_1_2_1_1_1" ~ "3",
                                  total == "1_2_1_1_2_1" ~ "4",
                                  TRUE ~ "0"
  ))
```

Ahora, si las condiciones crecieran en cantidad, podría ser más práctico tener todo parametrizado en un `data.frame` secundario con la caracterización de cada valor de `GESEPOCFENOTIPO_TipoI`

```
definicion <- data.frame(total = c("1_1_1_1_1_1", "1_1_1_1_1_2", "1_1_2_1_1_1", "1_1_1_2_1_1", "2_1_1_1_1_1",
                                   "1_1_2_2_1_1", "2_1_2_1_1_1", "2_1_2_1_1_1", "1_2_1_1_2_1"),
                         GESEPOCFENOTIPO_TipoI = c("1", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4"))

 
 BD_table6_1 %>% 
   unite(total,c(1,2,3,4,5,6),sep="_",remove= FALSE) %>%
   left_join(definicion) %>% 
   mutate(GESEPOCFENOTIPO_TipoI = if_else(is.na(GESEPOCFENOTIPO_TipoI), "0", GESEPOCFENOTIPO_TipoI))
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien, muchas gracias Patricio por tu respuesta.